# SPO 2013 content query web part: change link field if "link" field is empty

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part, hyperlink

I have a field of type hyperlink in a blog list and I want the title field to link to that URL if it's populated but to default to the list item URL if not.

I added the display (and internal) name "Link" to the `CQWP` link field and was pretty sure it worked...but somehow I must have deluded myself into thinking `MSFT` had actually made something easy because now when I remove the URL from the link field, it defaults to the URL of the page I'm on.

Is there a way using jQuery or other scripts, to do something like

> If link field is empty, render the item URL;if not, render the link
>   in the link field.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solution is to modify/create an Item Style in the `ItemStyle.xsl` file located at **Site Content > Style Library > XSL Style Sheets**.

It requires that you are experienced with XSLT.

If we say that you want the `CQWP` to just show a list of links to blogs, a suggested solution could look something like this:

```
<xsl:template name="BlogListItem" match="Row[@Style='BlogListItem']" mode="itemstyle">
    <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- Variable holding the value of the blog items link field -->
    <xsl:variable name="AlternativeLinkUrl">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'Custom_Internal_Link_Column_Name_Here'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
            <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <div class="item link-item">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>

        <!-- Insert anchor start tag depending on whether or not the Link field is set. -->
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- If it's not set, insert the default title link -->
            <xsl:when test="string-length($AlternativeLinkUrl) = 0"> 
                <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- otherwise insert the Link field url -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <a href="{$AlternativeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'">
                <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@OnClickForWebRendering"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams != 'True' and @OpenInNewWindow = 'True'">
                <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$OnClickTargetAttribute"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```